# Running batch file from PowerShell doesn't execute properly

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file, cmd, virtualenv

I am using Virtualenv to manage individual python sandboxed environments, and decided to make a simple batch file to activate the one I want. Using this file, it prompts for the name of the virtual environment, navigates to the directory, activates the environment with the command `.\\Scripts\activate` and then pops the directory back. It works great in the regular command prompt, but activating it in PowerShell does all the steps (as checked by turning off the `@echo off`) but doesn't actually activate the environment. My current code is:

```
::@echo off
title Virtual Python Manager
echo Enter the name of the virtual environment
set base=C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\VirtualEnviroments\
set /p "cho=>"
set path=%base% %cho%
set path=%path: =%
pushd %path%
.\\Scripts\activate
popd
```

Does anybody know how to make this work? In the directory there are multiple files with the same name, but the one that needs to run in order to activate is `activate.bat`

[activate files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO0Ps.png)

The commands work fine in both environments when typed by hand, just not in the batch file.

Comment: From `cmd.exe`, batch files run _in-process_. From PowerShell, they must run in a _child process_. PowerShell won't see any changes made to the environment of the child process. You'll have to use a `.ps1` file to configure the current PowerShell session.

Comment: @lit there is a activate.ps1 file in the directory, it this the file I need to run instead?

Comment: @Fort-P, sorry for my earlier comments. If you are in a PowerShell console, you should run `Activate.ps1`. It should be easy enough to change your .bat file to a .ps1 file.

Comment: @lit is it both that need to be converted (the custom one that I wrote and the original activate.bat,) or just one of them?

Comment: Convert your .bat file to .ps1. Do not change the files in .\Scripts\.